# Google adsense for wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, blogs, adsense, multisite

Here is my scenario:

I have a server where i want to host 50+ Wordpress websites. Each website needs to have a different domain name (i don't want to use sub domains) and each website must have independent google Adsense code so if something goes wrong due to google's rules the others should not be affected.

So my question is which one is more suitable:

1. Install each Wordpress site in a different directory on the server
2. Use the Multisite function that Wordpress offers

If number 2 is more appropriate i want to be absolutely sure that i can make it work with different domain names and have independent google Adsense codes

10x in advance.

P.S.

If something is not clear with my question let me know so i explain it in details.

Comment: AFAIK , for your specifications, the options are the same. from my experiance, multi-site has a lot of advantages but also disadvantages ( like plugin compatibility ). regarding adsense and different domain names, that is possible,

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you are aware of it or not. In multisite. The domain name changes but the core domain is same. Something like. Xxx.yourdomain.com. Where xxx can be anything.

As per adsense rules. It applies to website. So anything that is associated with your website. Rules do apply.

I guess you are confused about what you want. You said you don't want to use sub domain but wordpress multisite option is for making sub domain.

You would be violating google adsense policy if you use different accounts to like different content on same domain. Let me know if you want to know more